# setting up InspIRCd censoring

Tags: centos, irc, mirc

I have InspIRCd set up on my CentOS box, and it starts correctly. v `2.0.5`. I am having issues setting up the censoring, however. The directions for `2.0` and above tell you to put the `badwords` in the `inspircd.conf` file, and they will be censored. However, it doesn't work.

The format is:

```
<badword text="SWEARWORD" replace="REPLACEMENT">
```

I have several, for various expletives, and none work. When I send one of the expletives, it is not censored. What's happening?

Comment: How are you doing the testing?

Comment: Swearing on IRC...it's kinda funny

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my conf

```
<badword text="foo" replace="bar">
```

And reached the same problem you did.

To make it work, we must take two additional steps. First, we must load the censor module.

```
<module name="m_censor.so">
```

We also must make our channel censored, like so:

```
mode #channel +G
```

Here's the log on the op's (corsiKa's) screen:

```
join #corsiKa
:corsiKa!corsiKa@192.168.27.1 JOIN :#corsiKa
:glowirc1. 353 corsiKa = #corsiKa :@corsiKa
:glowirc1. 366 corsiKa #corsiKa :End of /NAMES list.
:bird!bird@192.168.27.1 JOIN :#corsiKa
privmsg #corsiKa :this is so foo
mode #corsiKa +G
:corsiKa!corsiKa@192.168.27.1 MODE #corsiKa +G
privmsg #corsiKa :this is so foo
```

So, corsiKa creates his brand new channel. He's the only one in it. Bird then joins it. CorsiKa says "this is so foo", then puts the censor on, and finally says "this is so foo" again.

And here's what the user (bird) of the channel saw:

```
join #corsiKa
:bird!bird@192.168.27.1 JOIN :#corsiKa
:glowirc1. 353 bird = #corsiKa :@corsiKa bird
:glowirc1. 366 bird #corsiKa :End of /NAMES list.
:corsiKa!corsiKa@192.168.27.1 PRIVMSG #corsiKa :this is so foo
:corsiKa!corsiKa@192.168.27.1 MODE #corsiKa +G
:corsiKa!corsiKa@192.168.27.1 PRIVMSG #corsiKa :this is so bar
PING :glowirc1.
```

Bird joins #corsiKa. He sees corsiKa say "this is so foo", and then put on the censor. But he never sees corsiKa say the bad word ("foo"). Instead, he sees bar come across.

So to make your badwords work:

1. Load your m_censor module
2. Define your badword tags
3. Make your channel `mode +G`